# Clearing/releasing OpenGL ES buffers

Tags: memory-management, opengl-es, framebuffer

I'm creating an extra framebuffer and renderbuffer for offscreen rendering in my OpenGL ES 1.1 iOS app. When I render into the additional renderbuffer I start to see memory warnings in the XCode console. **What is the proper way to "release", "clear" etc these additional buffers?**

I experimented with `glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)` but the memory warnings continued. Commenting out the rendering code causes the warnings to go away.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know what you mean, [`glClear`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glClear.xml) clears the content of the buffer (color, depth, stencil, whatever, depending on the bit flags) to a specific value. If you want to delete the buffers and free their resources, once you're finished with them, use [`glDeleteFramebuffers`](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glDeleteFramebuffers.xml) and [`glDeleteRenderbuffers`](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glDeleteRenderbuffers.xml) respectively, maybe with some OES suffix.

Othwerwise I don't know what you're talking about else and if these two cases don't apply you should just ignore such stupid warnings.

Comment: `glDeleteFramebuffersOES` and `glDeleteRenderBuffersOES` worked, thanks :-)